# Is there a way to create a variable which includes a value from a different variable in its name?

Tags: c++, variables

I'm trying to do a basic bubble sort algorithm, which orders numbers from lowest to highest. I have already made one that works, however it requires a new set of variables for every pass, and in order to be able to add an extra input number (there are only 6 at the moment) would take a lot of effort. I want a way for a new variable to be created every time the user enters a number, and that variable to be able to be generated on its own.

```
using namespace std;
int Acount = 0;
int SV = 0;
int x = 1;
int main()
{   
    cout << "Enter first number\n1: ";
    int I$Acount;
    cin >> I$Acount; 
    while (SV == 0)
    {
        Acount = Acount + 1;
        x = x + 1;
        cout << "Enter the next number or Press S to begin sort\n"<< x << ": ";
        if (_kbhit())
        {
            switch (_getch())
            { 
            case 's':
                SV = 1;
            }   
        }
        else
        {
            SV = 0;
            cin >> I$Acount;
        }
    }
    cout << "DONE";
    system("pause");
}
```

Issues with the code:

1. The increasing variable function `I$Acount` does not work (it is supposed to assign values to I0, I1, I2, ext...)
2. When the letter S is typed, the while statement loops with increasing value of x, until s is pressed again.

Comment: you want arrays, e.g. [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: Once you get vectors working put the sort in a function you can call with any vector.

Comment: It is not portable to use `$` in an identifier.